# Integrate Chrome Extension with Twilio API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, twilio-api

I would like to know if there is a way of using twilio message API from a chrome extension. I think it is not posible because I imagine that I would need to download some sort of Twilio library and I haven't found any CND on internet.
What I think I could do is to send a request from my extension to a hosted page and then send from there a request for the Twilio API, is that the only solution to do this?

Comment: What code have you tried? Here is a CDN for the Twilio client library: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twilio.js/news

Comment: I’d like to thank Jansent for the sugestion, I should have been more specific on my description. I need to use the message twilio API, particularly the whatsapp channel, so that CDN will not work for me, and for what I’ve seen on that page there is no twilio js library avaliable for whatsapp twilio api use. :(

Comment: Did you try the Twilio WhatsApp quickstart? They make a nodejs library for the Twilio Messaging API. https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/quickstart/node

Comment: Thank you @jassent that's something that I had ruled out because I tough there was no way of using node js in chrome extensions, but I found out this repo that I will check: https://github.com/ibnzUK/next-chrome-starter/blob/main/README.md

I will put the outcome here in a few days, I hope to have a good answer with your help.  Thanks!